# asmx returning nested json without object names

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, knockout.js, asmx

I have an asmx webservice which calls a methods that build a 2 level nested list of List each group contains a List. The json is being used to populated and accordion via knockout.js. When the nested object is returned to the jquery ajax call, the nested objects (as well as the stingified json) do not contain any object names.

I know I'm missing something basic, but am at a loss ... and have spent 2 days to no avail.

I'm expecting (please ignore the escape ):

```
[{\"__type\":\"Group\",\"id\":1488,\"name\":\"Baby Books\",\"categories\":[{\"__type\":\"GroupCategory\",\"id\":152,\"name\":\"Activity Books\",\"value\":\"Ignore\"}]}]
```

but am getting

```
[{\"id\":1488,\"name\":\"Baby Books\",\"categories\":[{\"id\":152,\"name\":\"Activity Books\",\"value\":\"Ignore\"}]}]
```

the classes are defined as:

```
public class Group
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public List<GroupCategory> categories;

    public Group(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.categories = new List<GroupCategory>();
    }
}

public class GroupCategory
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string value;


    public GroupCategory(int id, string name)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = CategoryValue.Ignore.ToString();
    }
}

public enum CategoryValue
{
    UseCategoryValue,
    Ignore,
    Included,
    Excluded,
}
```

the asmx and build methods are:

```
[WebMethod]
public List<Group> GetIncludeExcludeJson()
{
    var Groups =  new List<Group>();
    ShopAssistGroupHandler.getInExCategories(Groups);
    return Groups;
}
```

and

```
public static void getInExCategories(List<Group> Groups, CategoryValue defaultValue = CategoryValue.UseCategoryValue)
{
    var inexGroups = GroupCategoryHelper.GetGroups();

    try
    {
        foreach (GroupCategoryDictionary dGroup in inexGroups.Values)
        {
            var Group = new Group(dGroup.ParentGroupCategory.CategoryID, dGroup.ParentGroupCategory.Name);
            Groups.Add(Group);

            foreach (var groupCategory in dGroup.Values)
            {
                var category = new GroupCategory(groupCategory.CategoryID, groupCategory.Name);
                Group.categories.Add(category);
                if (defaultValue == CategoryValue.UseCategoryValue)
                {
                    category.value = groupCategory.ExtensionData == null
                                          ? ""
                                          : groupCategory.ExtensionData;
                    category.value = category.value == CategoryValue.Excluded.ToString()
                                          ? CategoryValue.Excluded.ToString()
                                          : CategoryValue.Ignore.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    category.value = defaultValue.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help - feeling very dumb ;-}
Abbott

Comment: Not sure I understand your wording, but why are you expecting `_type` members to be in the output? Serialising a C# object to JSON will only give the public properties. (or do you mean they are required for knockout or the control?)

Comment: They are required for knockout, since it uses foreach on the object list entries. I have another simple asmx test project that returns the __type information ... the difference is the object is declared with children constants populating the object. Mine is built on the fly.

Comment: That `__type` stuff is generated for WCF methods. Try decorating them with the WCF attributes `[DataContract]` and (or at least) `[KnownType(typeof(ClassNameHere))]` and see if that works. Never tried adding WCF attributes to non-WCF objects before, so they may simply be ignored by WebApi. Failing that, just add your own `__type` properties to each class.

Comment: I tried that which generated the expected string and object in js. When I try to ko.applybindings to the object it throw 'group' is not defined for:

Comment: I tried that which generated the expected string and object in js. When I try to ko.applybindings to the object it throw 'group' is not defined for:
<DIV id=accordion align=left>
    <DIV data-bind="foreach:group">
         <H3><A href="#" data-bind="text: name"> ...</A></H3>
    </DIV>
</DIV>

Comment: I am going to submit this as a knockout question, since the json object seems to be fine. I'm new to knockout and need help in that area. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Thanks @TrueBlueAussie. I've gotten past this. I did not need the __type info after all. I needed to code the knockout.js properly.